# Code for C# that allows you to Sum all Quantity from SQL Database with only name Condition without using datagridview

Tags: c#, vb.net

Please Help. What is the code for C# Windows Form that allows you to Sum all Quantity from SQL Database with only name Condition without using Datagridview. Thanks in advance

This be like: Checking if how many stocks are added automatically without using tables

Name = wheels
Result = Total Quantity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the datatable using ado.net and get the sum of your quantity. Here's some code to get you started

```
try
        {
            SqlConnection myPerformQueryConnection = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
            SqlDataAdapter myPerformQueryDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Name,Quantity FROM YourTableName", myPerformQueryConnection);
            SqlCommandBuilder myPerformQueryCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(myPerformQueryDataAdapter);
            DataTable myPerformQueryDataTable = new DataTable();
            myPerformQueryDataTable.Reset();
            myPerformQueryDataAdapter.Fill(myPerformQueryDataTable);
            if( myPerformQueryDataTable.Rows.Count>0)
            {
                decimal.TryParse(Convert.ToString(myPerformQueryDataTable.Compute("Sum(Quantity)", "Name='5070'")),out decimal sumObject) ;
                MessageBox.Show(sumObject.ToString("0.000"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: what is the sumObject ? it gives me error on that one

Comment: it also gives me error on decimal

Comment: Please give me an advice on how to display All Total Quantity of all items in from my database to Crystal Reports . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can query the sum like this:

```
var sum = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Name")=="wheels")
        .Sum(r =>  r.Field<int>("TotalQuantity"));
```